# C++ Linked list problem. i want to know why my output is correct. i think i didn't connect first node yet

Tags: c++, linked-list

here is my code.

list of problems

1.if i write "std::cout << this->first->new_data << std::endl;" in function void printout it will get an error you can look in my code i comment it already BUT in while loop it can show output and it correct WHY???

2.I haven't connected to the first node yet but the output is correct.WHY??
please help.

```
#include <iostream>

class Node { //this class create node 
public:    
    int new_data = 0; //set default value 
    Node* next = nullptr;
    
};

class linked_list { //Create linked list 
public:
    Node *first; //represent the first node of linked list;
    Node *last; //represent the last node of linked list;

    linked_list() {// constructor assign default this value to NULL;
        this->first = NULL;
        this->last = new Node();
    }

    void pushback(int add_data); //create abstract class for write out side class;
   
    void printout() { //show the values of linked list;

        while (this->first != NULL) {
            std::cout << this->first->new_data << std::endl;
            this->first = this->first->next;  
        }
        //std::cout << this->first->new_data << std::endl;<- this error/*Exception thrown: read                              access violation.this->first was nullptr.*/
        //std::cout << this->last->data << std::endl;<- this work
    }
};

void linked_list::pushback(int new_data) {//push from back function 

    if (this->first == NULL) { // if 1st node is NULL do this
        Node* new_node = new Node(); /*create new_node assign value and connected to linked list*/
        new_node->new_data = new_data;
        new_node->next = NULL;
        this->first = new_node;
        this->last = new_node;
    }
    else {
        Node* new_node = new Node(); /*create new_node assign value and connected to linked list*/
        new_node->new_data = new_data;
        new_node->next = this->last;
        this->last->next = new_node;
        this->last = new_node;
        this->last->next = NULL;
        
    }

}

int main()
{
    linked_list a;
    a.pushback(3);
    a.pushback(9);
    a.pushback(6);
    a.pushback(66);
    a.pushback(77);
    a.pushback(99);
    a.pushback(10000);
    a.pushback(10001);
    a.printout();

}
```

I want someone explain it to me and i will be glad if you wrote an example code about how I can fix it.

Comment: For your first question, don't tell me you keep the `while` loop when you uncomment the lines?

Comment: In the `pushback` function, the statement `new_node->next = this->last;` is not needed (and is actually wrong, but thankfully the later assignment `this->last->next = NULL` fixes that problem).

Comment: As for the problem of `printout()`, please explain to your [rubber duck](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging) where `this->first` is pointing after your loop.

Comment: You seem to be making a circular reference in else block of puch_back: new_node->new_data = new_data; and then new_node->next = this->last;

Comment: On a different note: The `NULL` macro is a C backward compatibility macro, it should not be used really. Instead use `nullptr` for null pointers-

Comment: And in the constructor, `this->last = new Node();` makes no sense and will lead to a memory leak.

Comment: `printout()` too seems to create a huge memory leak: the pointers to all nodes are lost (unless I missed something...). You should start with `Node* cursor = this->first` and only use that `cursor` variable to iterate over the list.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude sry i can't explain you because im confused to why it works lol. i think i need to go back to basic.Maybe i too hurry. thank you for your answers. Today everyone answers tell me what my weak point is and how bad I am now but i will keep practicing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok now i have solved the problem. Thank you for your comments and advice. I have studied about pointer and I quite understand. here is my code that i fixed. It might not be good but i think it is the best for me now.

```
#include <iostream>

class Node { //this class create node 
public:
    int new_data; //set default value 
    Node* next = nullptr;

};

class linked_list { //Create linked list 
public:
    Node* first; //represent the first node of linked list;
    Node* last; //represent the last node of linked list;

    linked_list() {// constructor assign default this value to NULL;
        this->first = nullptr;
        //this->last = new Node();->DO NOT DO THIS BECAUSE IT WILL CREATE MEMORY LEAK ["new" keyword it allocate memory].
    }

    void pushback(int add_data); //create abstract class for write out side class;
    void insertfromfront(int add_data);

    void printout() { //show the values of linked list;

        while (this->first != nullptr) {
            std::cout << this->first->new_data << std::endl;
            this->first = this->first->next;
        }
        
    }
};

void linked_list::pushback(int new_data) {//push from back function 

    if (this->first == nullptr) { // if 1st node is NULL do this
        Node* new_node = new Node(); /*create new_node assign value and connected to linked list*/
        new_node->new_data = new_data;
        new_node->next = nullptr;
        this->first = new_node;
        this->last = new_node;//this is for connect the node.
        /*std::cout << "an adress of value of new_node " << &new_node << std::endl;
        std::cout << "an dress of new_node " << new_node << std::endl;
        std::cout << "adress values of first " << this->first << std::endl;
        std::cout << "address value of last " << this->last << std::endl;
        std::cout << "address first " << &this->first << std::endl;
        std::cout << "address last " << &this->last << std::endl;*/
        
    }
    else {
        Node* new_node = new Node(); /*create new_node assign value and connected to linked list*/
        new_node->new_data = new_data;
        new_node->next = nullptr;
        this->last->next = new_node;//this is for connect the node
        this->last = new_node;//this put tail to the last of linked list.

    }

}


int main()
{
    linked_list a;
    std::cout << "Adress of a " << &a << std::endl;
    
    /*a.pushback(3);
    a.pushback(9);
    a.pushback(6);
    a.pushback(66);
    a.pushback(77);
    a.pushback(99);
    a.pushback(10000);
    a.pushback(10001);*/
    a.printout();
}
```